# Hot to model JSNI Functions with optional Parameters?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, jsni

I want to write a GWT JSNI wrapper function for the following JavaScript function.

```
object.cache(config);
```

where config is an object with the following optional parameters

```
- x Number
- y Number
- width Number
- height Number
- length Number
```

I think I would not be good to override all possible combinations of function arguments as a Java function.

**How do I model such a JavaScript function with many optional arguments as a JSNI Java function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would model the config object as a `JavaScriptObject`:

```java
public class Config extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected Config() { }

  public native final boolean hasX() /*-{ return this.x == null; }-*/;
  public native final double getX() /*-{ return this.x || 0; }-*/;
  public native final void setX(double x) /*-{ this.x = x; }-*/;
  public native final void unsetX() /*-{ delete this.x; }-*/;

  …
```

There are obviously other ways to model it (using `java.lang.Double` for instance) but that one is probably the most lightweight wrt the compiled JS output.

Or you could use `java.lang.Double` arguments, but you'll pay the price for the wrapper object:

```java
public native void cache(Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height, Double length) /*-{
  var cache = {};
  if (x != null) { cache.x = x.@java.lang.Double::doubleValue()(); }
  …
```

Finally, you could also use special values if that makes sense in your case:

```java
var config = {};
if (x >= 0) { config.x = x; }
```

Comment: Why do I need hasX and unsetX?